# Where can I go to learn about B&CG's specialty markup?

Tags: discussion, formatting

So, we've been talking about adding AutoCard for Magic. That brings up this question:

Where can I go to actually learn about the site's special markup features?

If I were a new poster working on my first question or answer, how would I actually know that B&CG SE has special support for go boards, chess boards, or (hypothetically) MTG cards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be on the tag for the game in question.

I see that [go](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/go) is lacking such help.  I'll try to get that rectified shortly.  That is the only site specific markup that I can think of right now.

Comment: Thanks, Pat! Is there a way to add notes to this page as well?  http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/editing-help It seems like the easiest place to navigate to if you're starting from scratch, just clicking on help you can get from the "Ask a Question" page.

Comment: @AlexP - no, that page is fixed site-wide.  It *may* be possible to edit it once we graduate, but I'm fairly certain nothing would be done before then.